# " Why does input() change a defined variable from integer to string type?"

Tags: python, python-3.x

"When using `input()`, the standard type (python 3.6) seems to be `string`, and a variable defined as integer is changed back to string. How can I change the default type of `input()` to string?"

it works when specifying type of the variable for input(), but it doesnt change input() default setting to int.

```
x=0

while x!=3:
   x=int(input("continue input until number is 3"))
```

Comment: There is no "default setting"... `input` returns a string, always.

Comment: Please do read the docs of how the functions and syntax work.

Answer (score 2):

Python names don't have types, the objects they are bound to have types. When you rebind a name (by assignment), the type of the object it previously referenced is immaterial; it has whatever type the newly bound object has. Since `input` returns `str`, any time you assign a name to the result of calling `input`, it's a `str`.

If you want to make it an `int`, you have to wrap the call in the `int` constructor as you've done. You may also want to catch exceptions so non-numeric input just asks again, rather than crashing the program:

```
x = 0

while x != 3:
    try:
        x = int(input("continue input until number is 3"))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's helpful!